# How to create a new test folder called Kotlin for android studio

Tags: android-studio

```
Android Studio 3.1 Canary 4
Build #AI-171.4444016, built on November 10, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1012-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.16-302.fc27.x86_64
```

Hello,

I have the following project structure. However, as I have some kotlin files I want to create a new folder called `kotlin` under `test` and create a new package and store all my kotlin files there.

Currently I have one called Java, but I want to create the kotlin, but can't seem to be able to find out how to do it.

I would like to do the same for `androidTest` as well, so I can separate all my java and kotlin files.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried, pressing CMD+alt+t on placing cursor on method name?. It will show a popup to create test methods. So It automatically saves the test classes?? Did you try this??

Comment: I don't have any issues creating test classes. But I want to organize my kotln files under the test folder called 'Kotlin' currently is a blue color. The java test folder is green. As I have kotlin classes in the java test folder, I want to put them in the Kotlin folder. However, I am not sure how to set the kotlin folder as a test folder (green color). Thanks.

Comment: OK I got that. Will get to you in some time.

Comment: @ankitpatidar, thanks for your help.

Comment: See if [these examples](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle) from jetbrains help. Also, you need to tell in `build.gradle` about which tests to use by assigning the `test.kotlin.srcDirs` property to the appropriate test dir. See this for more details: https://proandroiddev.com/using-kotlin-for-tests-in-android-6d4a0c818776

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would like to give credit to denvercoder9 who posted the link to the proandoriddev.com article which solved my problem.

In my build.gradle file I have the following which worked for both the test and androidTest folders. However, I needed to create the folders first.

```
sourceSets {
    main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/kotlin'] }
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
    androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
}
```

If anyone need any help on this you can reply back to this solution.

Answer (score 5):

- [Android Testing with Kotlin](https://fernandocejas.com/2017/02/03/android-testing-with-kotlin/)

**Basically, the idea is to showcase how we can test our android applications using Kotlin**, so as a first step we need to setup and prepare our environment by adding Kotlin dependencies in our *build.gradle* file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.5-2'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

...

dependencies {
  ...
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.6"

  ...
  testCompile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.6'
  testCompile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.0.6'
  testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.1.0"
  testCompile 'org.amshove.kluent:kluent:1.14'
}
```

**Now we need to set the dedicated directories for tests written in Kotlin**, this is done in our `sourceSets` section:

```
android {
  ...
  sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
    androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
  }
  ...
}
```

- [This tutorials](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html) walks us through the process of using Java and Kotlin in a single  IDEA project.