# Test android app writen in java with kotlin test

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, uitest

I'm trying to add UI-tests to my android app, decided to work with kotlin and not with Java.
I have added a new kotlin file to my "androidTest" folder 
I followed [this tutrial](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html#setup)
When I'm trying to run the test i'm getting:

```
Empty test suite.
```

just to emphasize - I'm writing to test in kotlin but the app is written in Java, is that even ok? or it can't even work?

My code:

```
package maakesher.com.black.packagename
import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test

@LargeTest
class ChangeTextBehaviorTest {

    private lateinit var stringToBetyped: String

    @get:Rule
    var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainMenuActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainMenuActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun initValidString() {
        // Specify a valid string.
        stringToBetyped = "Espresso"
    }

    @Test
    fun testSomeStuff() {
        // Type text and then press the button.
        onView(withId(R.id.start_button))
                .perform(click())
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't directly an answer, which is why I'm leaving a comment. I have no clue how to solve that, and I've looked up a bunch of answers, none of which solved it. Both IntelliJ and Android Studio appear to be affected. Dropping into a command line and running them manually at least fixed the unit tests ( `./gradlew test` or `gradlew test`), but I'm not sure if UI testing is covered by the test task. AS and IntelliJ does a lot of weird stuff that's instantly fixed when using a command line xd

Comment: Also, from my observations, manually compiling the tests (`gradlew test`) also fixes the "empty test suite" problem. But at that point it's already too late and the code is compiled and tested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new test folder called Kotlin for android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698957/how-to-create-a-new-test-folder-called-kotlin-for-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long night found the answer:
Needed to add this to mu Gradle file

```
 sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
    androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin/'
}
```